# How can i get the outbound traffic per ip on a 2901 Cisco router?

Tags: cisco, monitoring, traffic

What i need is to identify the internal source address using X amount of outbound traffic, and where the traffic is going (a domain or ip)

Currently, i have configured an "ip accounting" on my Fastehternet interface, where the source of the traffic its the public ip itself. I need also to identify the internal address where the packet is going from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netflow only gives me data of traffic per protocol.

I've used "ip accounting" command to solve this.

conf t
ip accounting interface output-packets
exit

then

show ip accounting

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution, Netflow, is [here](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2010/11/25/how-to-monitor-traffic-at-cisco-router-using-linux-netflow/)

I am using Netflow myself, but mostly for Cisco ASA firewalls.